# How to connect ubuntu via remote desktop with wayland on ubuntu22.04

Tags: wayland

I install waydroid on ubuntu22.04,And I need to access ubuntu via remote desktop.
I try to use tigervnc that work on X11,but waydroid only work on wayland.
How could I do ?